# In Unity, when an object collides with another, how would I send a raycast from that point of the object initiating collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere and a plane and I am dropping the sphere onto the plane. The plane is connected to a camera with a render texture pointing at a terrain. I am sending a raycast from the sphere into the plane which then sends another raycast at the point of collision on the plane through the camera onto the terrain and spawns a prefab. The issue I'm having is trying to figure out how to send the raycast from the sphere at the point of collision instead of what I'm currently doing by sending it from the transform.forward of the sphere making it only good for a single point of the sphere touching the plane.

Relevant code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Plane")
        {
            RaycastHit hit1;
            Ray ray1 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit1))
            {
                Vector2 localPoint = hit1.textureCoord;
                Ray ray2 = terrainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(localPoint);
                RaycastHit hit2;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray2, out hit2))
                {
                    StartCoroutine(SpawnObjectOnTerrain(hit2.point));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried playing around with OnCollisionEnter but couldn't quite figure out using collision.contacts[].point thinking that would be the answer but maybe I was doing it wrong.

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOLgR.png

The top portion of the image is currently what I have where only the z-axis from transform.forward can send a raycast when the sphere collides with the plane.

The bottom is what I want to achieve by being able to send out a raycast from the point of collision.

Comment: Raycasts dont cause collisions. They just are more what can you see. As for the rest i don't entirely understand what it is youre trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to get the point of collision of the sphere when colliding with the plane and use that point to send a raycast instead of just sending out a raycast from transform.forward of the the sphere. I just don't know how to collect the information to get that point on the sphere

Comment: what exactly did not work using `OnCollisionEnter` and the `collision.contacts[0].point`?

Comment: I only tried putting in place of the 'transform.position' in the line creating the Ray, ray1. It made it go to the first pixel in the corner of the plane.